# Creating jar files from selected java files using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project where i developed couple of java utility files and entire project is working good.

These utility files i placed in "utility" folder of my project.

Now i dont want everyone to see what i have coded in these utility files, so planning to create a jar file for these utility files.

Going forward i will place only this jar file in place of utility files.

So can some help how to create jar files for only selected java files in this utility folder? I saw many articles where they are converting the entire project into jar, but what i need is i want jar only to selected files.

So can some help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy guide: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

This link walks you through how to choose and pick which files you wish to have in the jar file you want to create.

Steps:

Right click the project you'll be converting into a jar > Export > Java > Jar File > Select the project, and view its contents *by clicking the arrow left of its name* >

Select or deselect the package/folder/etc you want to include or the parts of it by clicking it. The contents should appear on the right side of the menu which can be included or excluded from the jar build.